# finding master page control from another master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using two Different master page in my site. On one master page i am using a LoginStatus control. So wanna access that LoginStatus control from other. I have no great knowledge about how to find the controls from one master page to other.

Is there any way to achieving this. Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think w can access the one Maste page cotrol in other Master page. because both master page are not being used simulteneously.

Comment: You can check this tutorial for having multiple master pages
But i dont think u can access control of one from the other

[Multiple Master pages in asp.net][1]


  [1]: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Ashish1/Masters06152006013417AM/Masters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well if there is single master page and content page you can access control using

```
  Label lblinMaster = (Label)This.Master.FindControl("Label1");
```

and the same way to access control in nested master page you can use following.

```
Label lblinParentMaster = (Label)Master.Master.FindControl("Label1");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using nested master pages, you cannot access one master page from another.
A Page would normally use only one master page at a time.

The users login status, however is not dependent on the LoginStatus control.
You can show this status everywhere.

Refer: [ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get an idea about the right control to use.